# How can I correctly label stratum with numbers using ggplot and ggalluvial?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a bump plot to visualize time series data using ggalluvial. I would like to label the center of each stratum using the value "percent" that pertains to that stratum. I cannot seem to get the labels correct. For example, the values at the top (12, 14, 8) should be in the center of the 18-30 lode, but they are found up top for some reason on the 30-40 lode. Is there a way to correctly label this? I also considered geom_sankey_bump.

```
df <- data.frame(age = c(
  '18-30', '18-30',  '18-30', 
  '30-40', '30-40', '30-40',
  '40-50', '40-50', '40-50',
  '50+', '50+', '50+'),
  year = c(2012, 2013, 2014,
           2012, 2013, 2014,
           2012, 2013, 2014,
           2012, 2013, 2014),
  percent = c(12, 14, 8,
              44, 54, 50,
              21, 32, 45,
              10, 13, 30))

plot <- ggplot(data =df, 
       aes(x = factor(year),
           y = percent,
           alluvium = age,
           node = factor(year),
           stratum = age,
           label = percent) ) 

plot + 
  geom_stratum(aes(stratum = age), decreasing = F, width = 3/4) + 
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = age), alpha = 1, decreasing = F, 
                     width = 3/4,
                     knot.prop = T,
                     curve_type = "linear") +
  ggfittext::geom_fit_text(stat = "stratum", width = 1/4, min.size = 3) + 
  ggtitle("Marijuana Crime Rate") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  xlab(NULL) + 
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image: Bump plot with incorrect labels]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To place the labels at the correct positions you have to use identical parameters for `stat_stratum`, i.e. use `width=3/4` and `decreasing=FALSE` as you did for `geom_stratum`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalluvial)

plot <- ggplot(data =df, 
               aes(x = factor(year),
                   y = percent,
                   alluvium = age,
                   node = factor(year),
                   stratum = age,
                   label = percent) ) 

plot + 
  geom_stratum(aes(stratum = age), decreasing = F, width = 3/4) + 
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = age), alpha = 1, decreasing = F, 
                width = 3/4,
                knot.prop = T,
                curve_type = "linear") +
  ggfittext::geom_fit_text(stat = "stratum", width = 3/4, decreasing = FALSE, min.size = 3) + 
  ggtitle("Marijuana Crime Rate") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  xlab(NULL) + 
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

Comment: Yes that worked, thanks. "Decreasing" effects the way the stratum are stacked? Or does it build the flows in increasing vs decreasing order.

Comment: @Milan the `decreasing` parameter only affects the vertical order of the elements at each axis (in your case, the axes are the years). By "build", if you mean their "z-ordering" (i.e. overlap order, e.g. red behind purple above), then this is determined internally based on color aesthetics and not directly controlled by the user.

Comment: Making sure all layers use the same parameter values can be tedious, so FYI these can also be set as options; see e.g. [the documentation for `stat_alluvium()`](http://corybrunson.github.io/ggalluvial/reference/stat_alluvium.html#package-options).